# Visual studio 2019 freezes when debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio, freeze, visual-studio-debugging

I have a strange problem. When debugging C# Windows app (but only one app, others are well), Visual Studio freezes (usually when inserting breakpoint). Restarting PC, resetting VS settings, updating VS, cleaning .vs directory, switching off anti-virus - doesn't help. When running from Console - everything is ok in application. But trying to attach debbugger - same problem.... I don't have more ideas...

Comment: Hi guy, any update for this issue? Please check if my answer helps you handle this issue and let us know if it helps or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Visual studio 2019 freezes when debugging

Please try the following steps:

**1)** disable any third party extensions under **Extensions**-->**Manage Extensions** in case some other extensions cause this abnormal behavior.

**2)** close VS, delete `bin` and `obj` folder and then restart your project. If you project uses packages.config to manage nuget packages, please run `update-package -reinstall` under **Tools**-->**NuGet Package Manager**-->**Package Manager Console** to prevent nuget package references from getting confused and causing debug blocking.

**Then**, `rebuild your project` and then debug it to test.

**3)** run `devenv /safemode` on [Developer Command Prompt for VS2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/developer-command-prompt-for-vs) to start a pure VS and then debug your project to test again.

**4)** If it does not work, you could create a new winform project in VS2019 and then migrate the old content into the new one to test whether the issue still persists. And if it succeeded, it is a better solution to avoid this issue.

**Besides**, if **step 4** still not work, I think the issue is related to your code. When you debug your project, you could open Debugging-->Windows-->**Threadd** to check which process is blocking. And you should check your code carefully.

**In addition**, you could also `share your sample with us here` so that we can troubleshoot the issue more quickly.